# REW (Room EQ wizard) not working?

Tags: sound, java, openjdk

REW (Room EQ Wizard) has stopped working.
The following warning pops up.

“Unable to access the selected device to
AudioFire8a [plughw:0,0] does not have any line supporting
PCM_SGNED 44100.0 Hz, 32 bit, 16 channel, 64 bytes/frame,
little-endian
Try a different sample rate”

Is there away to over come this problem?
How do I change the sample rate?

Ubuntu Studio with my Echo FireWire 8 sound card using the
FFADO Driver has been great, very stable with jack.
I am using a Reaper DAW on 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit

Any help much appreciated.

Davyd

Systems details listed.
Ubuntu Studio on 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Echo FireWire 8 , FFADO Driver
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)